# How to perform assertion on CodedUI Testing?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm creating an automation script using CodedUI (Visual Studio 2013 Premium), where I want to perform assertion on "**Proc 0001M-0005MZZ**" which is my expected value. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Assert` class which has several methods for assertions -
i.e `IsTrue()` and each of those has several overloads 
for different situations.

Comment: I fixed the earlier query on "assertion", thanks again! 
I have another question - I want to put an assertion on a display window where the pass criteria is an "empty display". Meaning, when the display window is blank/empty the test passes. How do I write the code for that? :) would really appreciate your reply.

Comment: when you say empty you mean with no controlls inside it or it's text/content is empty?

Comment: No text content (blank).

Comment: try this - Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)). please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Will let you know how it goes once I implement that. :)